# Bing Maps v8 doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I am trying the new Bing Maps v8.
I follow one of the firsts examples:
http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapSync+HTML

It works. But when I add a text, like `test`, it stops showing the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        test
        <div id='printoutPanel'></div>
        <div id='myMap'></div>


        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function loadMapScenario()
            {
                var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
                });

            }

            window.onload = loadMapScenario;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The word `test` in the 7th line makes it to stop working.
Any idea?

Comment: What exactly does "stop working" mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: It doesn't show the map when I add the `test` word. I have tested it with Internet Explorer 11, Google Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m, and Firefox 45.0.2. You can copy/paste the code and test it by yourself. If you remove the word `test` you will see that it shows the map again.

Comment: @Nekketsu : it works fine for me in Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m,here is demo for that http://jsbin.com/repovotafi/edit?html,output , please check and provide feedback.

Comment: Wow, it's working for me. I just saw one differrence, there is not `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If I remove it from my HTML, it works also locally for me. Any idea why `<!DOCTYPE html>` is making it fail? Can you please test it locally? Create an HTML file and open it directly from your hard drive.

Comment: it working perfect local too for me.

Comment: shall I post as answer ? without <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Ok. But I think there should be another question/answer regarding <!DOCTYPE html>. I can't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doctype shouldn't be the cause for failure here, in fact it should reduce issues as that is the doctype used for HTML5, which the map uses.

The code you provided should work. Looking into this I found that the width of the map is never being set, and as such it ends up being 0. When no width or height is specified for the map, the map tries to use the dimensions of it's parent. It appears that adding the text into body is causing the calculation to be incorrect. I'll have the dev team look into this.

Also, I would only use the Sync method of loading the map if you were migrating old code that needed to run synchronously. If you are creating a new app you should load the map control asynchronously as it will allow your page to load faster.  http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapAsync+HTML

Comment: I get the same issue with synchronous loading and with asynchronous loading. If I get the http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapAsync+HTML example, it works correctly. If I add some text to the body, it stops working. If I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, then it works even when I add text to the body. I'd like to use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration, and add text to the body, and make it work, but I can't.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the map is evaluating a width of 0 since a width was not specified. You can add  style="width:100%" to the map div to fix the issue. I'll have the dev team look into why the map is evaluating a width of 0 in this case.

Comment: Correction, adding the following style to the map corrects the issue:  style="height:100vh;width:100vw" alternatively you can provide a pixel height and a width.

Comment: Checking with the dev team, and also testing this scenario against other map platforms, this is working as expected. When no dimensions are specified for the map it tries to inherit the dimensions from it's parent. But if the parent doesn't have any dimensions, the width/height end up being 0.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works with the style you provided. It's strange, because in previous versions of Bing Maps, it wasn't necesary to prive the height/width.

Comment: In previous versions of Bing Maps is was absolutely necessary to provide a height, width and a position value, otherwise it wouldn't render in about 30% of browsers